# using $exists in Mongo with dynamic key names and the native driver for node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a document in a collection like so:

```
{
  container : {
    P39433: 2,
    P30213: 4
  }
}
```

The values 'P39433' and 'P30213' are dynamically generated in the program. I can run the following query using the dot notation against mongo directly and I get the desired result

```
db.collection.findOne({ "container.P00000" : { $exists : false } })
```

I get the document back. i.e. I only want to get the document if the field does not exist.

My question is how can I run that query in Node using the native driver when the value `P00000`
is contained in a variable.

My usual solution is to structure the query like below but it does not return a result.

```
var fieldName = 'P00000';
var dynObj = {};
dynObj[fieldName] = { $exists : false };
db.collection.findOne( { "container" : dynObj });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're close.  Try this:

```
var fieldName = 'P00000';
var dynObj = {};
dynObj["container." + fieldName] = { $exists: false };
db.collection.findOne(dynObj);
```

**Update**

Now that Node.js 4+ supports [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), you can create `dynObj` in one step as:

```
var dynObj = {
    ["container." + fieldName]: { $exists: false }
};
```

Comment: That's great, works perfectly, thanks a lot. I tried a few different variants just not that one.